# Predictive Auto Scaling for AWS ECS Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-auto-scaling

##### Motivation

- I currently have a number of services deployed to ECS with EC2 Launch Type, but I can change that if needed.
- I would like to use the [EC2 Predictive Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ec2-auto-scaling-predictive-scaling.html) feature since traffic is very periodic (peak in day, slack at night).
- [ECS Service Auto-Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-auto-scaling.html) uses [Application Auto-Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/userguide/what-is-application-auto-scaling.html) and only supports these policies:

  - Target Tracking Scaling
  - Scheduled Scaling
  - Step Scaling

##### Questions

- Is it possible to use EC2 Predictive Auto Scaling while still deploying to ECS? If so, what is the simplest approach?
- Is there a reason AWS hasn't included Predictive Auto Scaling in ECS Service Auto-Scaling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a particular reason why predictive autoscaling is limited to EC2 instances only other than customers' interest/demand. I'd suggest you open an issue on the [public roadmap](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues) for the AWS containers services so that the team can track the request and get more insides about the use case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I created a feature request [here](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1574). If anyone is interested in this feature, please upvote the proposal.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, is there no way to leverage EC2 Auto Scaling when deploying to ECS, not even as a workaround?

Comment: Thanks. Not that I am aware of.